# How to program an interchangeable library?

Tags: c++, user-interface

I'm currently programming a small library with abstract classes. Its a library that offers simple GUI creation classes, like `widget`, `main_window` etc.

My goal is to code an application using interfaces and factory functions to creates actual objects. I use cmake for my project (for info but doesnt really matters). I'd like to include in my lib the abstract classes (easy) and different engine (like qt5_engine, gtk_engine, ...).

The client(my application) using the lib can see only the abstract interfaces, and factory functions(methods, lambdas, builder classes??). When building the lib, I choose which engine to build (only one) to get libmy_lib.so. My application will use libmy_lib.so, no matter if its compiled with my qt5_engine or gtk_engine (staticly linked into my_lib for each engine)

So that finally, I can simply overwrite libmy_lib.so compiled with a different engine to change the GUI used by my application. But I also like to know of a clean way to implement such lib with different engine, to get a clean code, the 'best pratices' for lib programming in other word.

I kinda found the way to ask it, and so, the way to search for it >< I accepted an answer which is the part for the 'change le lib file to change the GUI' but if you have references to library coding the clean way, the modern way, that would be awesome...

Thx

Comment: Do you include linking in the "recompiling" step? You could relink your code to the library of choice with little difficulty.

Comment: Sorry, my question is not correctly formulated. I'd like to know if there is a good way to code the same interface to a lib. Like using different namespace for the lib and using namespace alias to show the application the interface functions, Or using the same header file, with two different definition files (uh that one seems ugly) Geez already -2, guess my english aint good enough to ask questions, sorry :(

Comment: No, your English is fine, it's just that the question is unclear. First you say "without recompiling", but then you suggest using different namespaces and changing aliases, which is something you do *in the source code* and which would thus necessitate recompiling.

Comment: My english is fine on paper, but it does not clearly ask what's in my head, leading to confusion and unclear question ;) Add to this that some aspect of c++ (like the linking part) is little known to me, you get the messy question here. I'll try to reformulate then thx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up "ABI compatibility". The Qt/KDE projects have a good guide about that:

https://wiki.qt.io/Qt-Version-Compatibility
[https://community.kde.org/Policies/Binary_Compatibility_Issues_With_C++](https://community.kde.org/Policies/Binary_Compatibility_Issues_With_C%2B%2B)

The extreme version of that would be the "Hourglass Interface" pattern, where the binary interface of the library is pure C, but there's an inlined C++ API above it and a C++ implementation below:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PVYdHDm0q6Y

EDIT: Just wanted to add a clarification: Where these guides talk about compatibility between different versions, your libraries would have to adhere to the same restrictions for different backends.